# Highcharts graph: tooltip when mouse over label

Tags: highcharts, label, tooltip, mouseover

On Highcharts graph, can we show a tool tip when mouse over label
other tool tip than shown when mouse over columns (point)?

thanks
Chanan

Comment: Mouseover label, you mean in axis or in other object?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to achieve this - you need two steps:

1.) For the xAxis or yXis, set the labels options; the 'formatter' property should include a html title attribute. Utilise a function for dynamic outputs. Ensure the 'useHTML' property is set to true. eg:

```
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function () {                                                                                    
            return '<div class="label_tip" style="font-size:12px; font-weight:500;" title="'+this.value+'">'+this.value+'</div>'; }
```

2.) Use any tooltip library to alter the titles to a tooltip. This should be triggered in the Highcharts load or redraw event.

In this example I'm using qTips to create the label tooltips - http://jsfiddle.net/amichaels/quXLg/